# how to send email template html page?

Tags: phpmailer

> Im using **PHPMAILER 5.2.7 !**

```
  $to=$row['email'];
  $at=$row['updated_at'];
  $subject = "Your Password has been changed";
  $body = "<body background='red' style='bgcolore:red;'><p>Hello < ".$u." > your password has been 
  changed at ".$at." ! </p>";
  $SITEEMAIL='support@test.tn';
  $mail = new Mail();
  $mail->setFrom($SITEEMAIL);
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->subject($subject);
  $mail->body($body);
  $mail->send();
```

> **how can i switch the $body content with a html page (template) ?? tried to directly past the code inside $body but i dosen't work !**

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have sending/delivery failed, or only the content of delivered mail was malformed? Does your e-mail sending works OK with plaintext message? I see several strange things in your `$body` text, try using more simple contents from this sample first. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

In any case, you should also call `$mail->isHTML(true)` before sending.

Comment: Well yes ! $mail->isHTML(true) + i copied the the html code so i forgot about switching the " " and ' ' ! problem solved thank u !

Comment: PHPMailer really doesn't care how you do this. You can use either plain PHP to generate your message body, or use a templating system like Twig, Smarty, or Blade. Get it to generate your content, and pass it to `Body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several strange things in your $body text, try using more simple contents from this sample first. [github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example)

In any case, you should also call `$mail->isHTML(true);` before sending.